# jquery sort out li

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-lists

I have code

```
<ul id="list">
 <li>test</li>
 <li class="header">test</li>
 <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

I need execute this code

(use jquery)

```
var items = $("#list li");

$.each(items, function (key, value) {
 if ($(value).hasClass(".header")) { 
    ... Do Something ...
    }
}
```

this code doesn't work, because value == 'test'

**Excuse, my English is awful**

Comment: questions are best when there's actually a question mark in them somewhere. :)

Comment: can you be more specific on what the output should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a . in your hasClass functon while passing class name. Change it to:

```
var items = $("#list li");  
    $.each(items, function (key, value){  
        if ($(value).hasClass("header")){      
            alert('Hi');
            //Do Something
        } 
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what you mean by `value == 'test'`. There's nothing like that in your question.

Your `$.each()` is missing its closing `)`.

Also, your `.hasClass` should not include the `.` in the class name.

So this:

```
.hasClass(".header")
```

should be:

```
.hasClass("header")
```

Although, if you're interested in running code against only the items that have a class, just do a [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) before [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

```
items.filter('.header').each( function (key, value) {
    ... Do Something ...
});
```

If you have no other use for the collection, then you could modify the selector like this:

```
$('#list li.header').each( function (key, value) {
    ... Do Something ...
});
```

But only if you have no other need to cache all of the `<li>` elements.

Comment: thanks) i know about '#list li.header' and filter method, But in my case i use 'if ($(value).hasClass("header"))' specially)